# Не присваивается параметры в ксс, когда я пытаюсь присвоить классу или id

Tags: html, css

```css
#term {
  text-decoration-style: dotted;
  text-decoration-color: black;
}

.sss {
  text-decoration-style: dotted;
  text-decoration-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>home3</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    h1,
    h2 {
      text-align: center
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="home3.css">
</head>
<h1>HTML Tutorial</h1>
<h2>
  <hr>What is HTML?</h2>
<div>
  <p>
    <b>Hypertext Markup Language <span id="term">(HTML)</span>
            </b>is the standard markup language for creating web pages and web applications.
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>
    Web browsers receive <span class="sss">HTML</span> documents from a web server or from local storage and render the documents into multimedia web pages. <span class="sss">HTML</span> describes the structure of a web page semantically and originally
    included cues for the appearance of the document.
  </p>
</div>


<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Через девтулзы прекрасно видно что применяются. Только вот вы изменили стили подчёркивания, а у этих элементов никакого подчёркивания нету, поэтому визуально изменяться тут нечему

Comment: Добавьте `text-decoration-line: underline;` или другой соответствующий + не мешало бы HTML код поместить внутрь тега `body`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
h1, h2 {
    text-align: center;
    }
    #term {
    text-decoration: underline dotted black;
    }
    .sss {
    text-decoration: underline dotted black;
    }
```

```html
    <body>
    <h1>HTML Tutorial</h1>
    <h2>
    <hr>What is HTML?
    </h2>
    <div>
    <p>
    <b>Hypertext Markup Language <span 
    id="term">(HTML)</span>
    </b>is the standard markup language for 
    creating web pages and web applications.
    </p>
    </div>

    <div>
    <p>
    Web browsers receive <span 
    class="sss">HTML</span> documents from a 
    web server or from local storage and render 
    the documents into multimedia web pages. 
    <span class="sss">HTML</span> describes the 
    structure of a web page semantically and 
    originally
    included cues for the appearance of the 
    document.
    </p>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Для того, чтобы это работало, в text-decoration нужно прописать 3 свойства: вид подчеркивания (под строкой, над строкой, зачеркивает строку и т.д.), стиль подчеркивания (пунктир, сплошная линия, двойная линия и т.д.) и цвет подчеркивания

Comment: почему вы добавляете закрывающую </p> ?
это же строка/параграф, который не имеет закрывающего тега

Comment: Тег `<p></p>` - парный. Имеет открывающую и закрывающую часть, между которыми и находится текст, который пользователь увидит в браузере.

Comment: спасибо
а с чем же я его тогда спутал